# isn't defined in the WSDL file

Tags: soap, wsdl

I give the following WSDL Request for Logging out..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><Logout xmlns="http://tempuri.org/wsdl/"><vsSecurityKey>0</vsSecurityKey></Logout></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

And I get the below response:

> faultcode: SOAP-ENV:Server
>
> faultstring: WSDLReader: The operation requested in the Soap message
>   with soapAction http://tempuri.org/wsdl/Logout isn't defined in the
>   WSDL file.  This may be because it is in the wrong namespace or has
>   incorrect case

I'm not sure what is the wrong namespace here. Any thoughts..

Following is the WSDL File (I have taken the parts that are related to Logout)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated 04/04/06 by Microsoft SOAP Toolkit WSDL File Generator, Version 1.02.813.0 -->
<definitions name="nsi_soap" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlns="http://tempuri.org/wsdl/" xmlns:typens="http://tempuri.org/type" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:stk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap-toolkit/wsdl-extension" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"> 
  <types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/type" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    </schema>
  </types>
  <message name="SOAP_2.Logout">
    <part name="vsSecurityKey" type="xsd:string"/>
  </message>
  <message name="SOAP_2.LogoutResponse">
  </message>
  <message name="SOAP_2.Login">
    <part name="vsUserId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="vsPassword" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="vlOrgId" type="xsd:int"/>
  </message>
  <message name="SOAP_2.LoginResponse">
    <part name="Result" type="xsd:string"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="SOAP_2SoapPort">
    <operation name="CreateMergeRequest" parameterOrder="vsSecurityKey vsNSN0 vsNSN1 vsNSN2 vsNSN3 vsNSN4 vsNSN5 vsNSN6 vsNSN7 vsNSN8 vsNSN9 vsUser">
      <input message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.CreateMergeRequest"/>
      <output message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.CreateMergeRequestResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Update" parameterOrder="vsSessionKey vsNSN vsSurname vsForename1 vsForename2 vsForename3 vsDOB vsPreferredName vsNameDOBVerification vsResidentialStatus vsResidentialVerification vsGender vsUser vsAltSurname vsAltForename1 vsAltForename2 vsAltForename3 vsAltPreferredName vsAltNameDobVerification">
      <input message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.Update"/>
      <output message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.UpdateResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Insert" parameterOrder="vsSecurityKey vsSurname vsForename1 vsForename2 vsForename3 vsDOB vsPreferredName vsNameDOBVerification vsResidentialStatus vsResidentialStatusVerification vsGender vsAlias_lastname vsAlias_forename1 vsAlias_forename2 vsAlias_forename3 vsAlias_prefered vsAlias_NameDOBVerification vsOverride vsUser">
      <input message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.Insert"/>
      <output message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.InsertResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Search" parameterOrder="vsSecurityKey vsNSN vsName vsDOB vsGender vsResidentialStatus vsUser">
      <input message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.Search"/>
      <output message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.SearchResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Logout" parameterOrder="vsSecurityKey">
      <input message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.Logout"/>
      <output message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.LogoutResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Login" parameterOrder="vsUserId vsPassword vlOrgId">
      <input message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.Login"/>
      <output message="wsdlns:SOAP_2.LoginResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="SOAP_2SoapBinding" type="wsdlns:SOAP_2SoapPort">
    <stk:binding preferredEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="Logout">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/action/SOAP_2.Logout"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://tempuri.org/message/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://tempuri.org/message/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Login">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/action/SOAP_2.Login"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://tempuri.org/message/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://tempuri.org/message/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="nsi_soap">
    <port name="SOAP_2SoapPort" binding="wsdlns:SOAP_2SoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="https://nsicompl.nsi.govt.nz/interface/nsi_soap.wsdl"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: @John...try changing all instances of http://tempuri.org/wsdl/ to http://tempuri.org/ in your wsdl file above

Comment: @MikeTWebb, I'm using a Web Service. So in this case, I would not be able to make changes to the WSDL file, as Im just a user. Just to understand your response, I should request them to change: the targetNameSpace and xmlns:wsdlns to http://tempuri.org/. Is that correct

Comment: Did you know that the SOAP Toolkit is ancient and unsupported?

Comment: @JohnSaunders:) Yes, however, the provider of this Web Service, only supports this. I'm left with no choice, as I want to use it. Any help on finding the incorrect namespace error from their WSDL file, will help me in informing them how to fix this issue for me.

Comment: It may not be an actual incorrect namespace. The SOAP toolkit was created before the SOAP standards were very standard. It may not be practical to use this service. You really need to decide if you want to use a service from someone using decade-old, unsupported technology.